# How to get the true x and y coordinates of a JTextField

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, jtextfield

I had an issue with a piece of code I was writing where I was adding JPanel's inside of others to form a layout. The issue is that after the window is displayed I needed to get the x and y coordinates of one of the text fields but whenever I try using the `getX()` and `getY()` methods they keep returning 0. I have verified that the `getX()` and `getY()` methods are being called after the window is initialized and displayed. How can I fix this and get the actual coordinates of the text field.

This is window code:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.LineBorder;
import javax.swing.event.CaretEvent;
import javax.swing.event.CaretListener;


public class GraphicsPanel extends JFrame implements ActionListener, CaretListener{

    JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel();
    JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel();
    JPanel animationPanel = new JPanel();
    JPanel bottomPanel = new JPanel();
    JPanel text = new JPanel();

    PokemonLearnsets info = new PokemonLearnsets();

    HealthBar healthBar1 = new HealthBar();
    HealthBar healthBar2 = new HealthBar();

    JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea();
    JTextField response = new JTextField();

    int health1 = 100;
    int total1 = 100;
    int health2 = 100;
    int total2 = 100;
    int startOfRect = 1;
    int p1MonNum = -1;
    int waitTime = 20;
    int p2MonNum = -1;

    TextInterface theText;

    Icon allIcons[][];
    JLabel p1Gif;
    JLabel p2Gif;

    JPanel mainBuilderPanel = new JPanel();
    JPanel builderPanel = new JPanel();
    JPanel builderMessagePanel = new JPanel();

    JPanel monPanels [] = new JPanel[6];
    JPanel imagePanels[] = new JPanel[6];
    JPanel namePanels[] = new JPanel[6];
    JPanel movePanels[] = new JPanel[6];

    JPanel allMoves[][] = new JPanel[6][4];

    JTextField names[] = new JTextField[6];

    JTextField moves[][] = new JTextField[6][4];

    JButton validate = new JButton("Validate");

    JLabel tempImages[] = new JLabel[6];
    JLabel emptyLabels[] = new JLabel[6];

    AutoSuggestor [] nameSuggestions = new AutoSuggestor[6];

    AutoSuggestor [][] moveSuggestions = new AutoSuggestor[6][4];


    public GraphicsPanel(String name){

        super(name);

        setupTeamBuilderPanel();

//      setupBattlePanel();
    }

    private void setupTeamBuilderPanel() {

        Container c = getContentPane();

        mainBuilderPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        mainBuilderPanel.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.BLACK, 2));
        builderPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 0));
        builderPanel.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.BLACK, 1));
        builderMessagePanel.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.BLACK, 2));

        for (int i = 0; i < monPanels.length; i ++) {

            monPanels[i] = new JPanel();
            imagePanels[i] = new JPanel();
            namePanels[i] = new JPanel();
            movePanels[i] = new JPanel();

            names[i] = new JTextField();

            names[i].addCaretListener(this);

            emptyLabels[i] = new JLabel();
            tempImages[i] = emptyLabels[i];

            monPanels[i].setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.BLACK, 3));
            imagePanels[i].setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.BLACK, 3));
            movePanels[i].setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.BLACK, 3));

            monPanels[i].setLayout(new GridLayout(0 ,1));
            namePanels[i].setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 0));
            movePanels[i].setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 1));
            imagePanels[i].setLayout(new BorderLayout());

            namePanels[i].add(new JLabel("      Name:"));
            namePanels[i].add(names[i]);
            imagePanels[i].add(tempImages[i]);
            imagePanels[i].add(namePanels[i], BorderLayout.SOUTH);
            monPanels[i].add(imagePanels[i]);

            for (int k = 0; k < moves[i].length; k ++) {

                moves[i][k] = new JTextField();

                allMoves[i][k] = new JPanel();

                allMoves[i][k].setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 1));

                allMoves[i][k].add(new JLabel(" Move " + Integer.toString(k + 1) + ":"));
                allMoves[i][k].add(moves[i][k]);
                allMoves[i][k].add(new JLabel());
                allMoves[i][k].add(new JLabel());

                movePanels[i].add(allMoves[i][k]);

            }

            monPanels[i].add(movePanels[i]);

            builderPanel.add(monPanels[i]);

        }

        String welcomeMessage = "";

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i ++) {

            welcomeMessage += " ";

        }

        welcomeMessage += "Welcome to the Teambuilder!";

        setupSuggestions();

        validate.addActionListener(this);

        builderMessagePanel.add(new JLabel(welcomeMessage));
        mainBuilderPanel.add(builderMessagePanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        mainBuilderPanel.add(validate, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        mainBuilderPanel.add(builderPanel);

        c.add(mainBuilderPanel);
    }

    private void setupBattlePanel() {

        Container c = getContentPane();

        mainPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout());
        bottomPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout());

        animationPanel.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.BLACK, 3));
        animationPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 2));

        mainPanel.add(animationPanel);

        buttonPanel.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.BLACK, 3));
        buttonPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout(5));
        buttonPanel.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
//      buttonPanel.add(new JLabel("                 "));
//      buttonPanel.add(new JButton("Testing"));
//      buttonPanel.add(new JButton("Testing"));
//      buttonPanel.add(new JButton("Testing"));
//      buttonPanel.add(new JButton("Testing"));

        bottomPanel.add(buttonPanel);

        text.setLayout(new GridLayout());
        text.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.BLACK, 3));
        text.add(response);

        bottomPanel.add(text);


        textArea.setWrapStyleWord(true);
        textArea.setLineWrap(true);

        textArea.setEditable(false);
        textArea.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
        JScrollPane textAreaPane = new JScrollPane(textArea, ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED,
        ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);

        textAreaPane.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.BLACK, 3));

        mainPanel.add(textAreaPane);

        c.add(mainPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        c.add(bottomPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

    }

    private void setupSuggestions() {

        ArrayList<String> allPossibleMoves = new ArrayList<String>();

        Collections.addAll(allPossibleMoves, info.getAllMoves());

        for (int i = 0; i < 6; i ++) {

            for (int k = 0; k < 4; k ++) {

                moveSuggestions[i][k] = new AutoSuggestor(moves[i][k], allPossibleMoves, Color.WHITE.brighter(), Color.BLACK, Color.BLACK, 0.75f);
                moveSuggestions[i][k].setTextField(moves[i][k]);

            }

        }

    }

    public void writeToScreen(String writing) {
        String current = textArea.getText();
        textArea.setText(current + writing);
    }

    public void updateAll() {

        mainPanel.updateUI();
        bottomPanel.updateUI();
        mainBuilderPanel.updateUI();

    }

    public void setTextInterface(TextInterface text) {
        theText = text;
        response.addActionListener(theText.action);
    }

    public void drawMons(String name1, String name2) {

        animationPanel.removeAll();

        ImageIcon secImage = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("SpritesFront/" + name2 + ".gif"));
        secImage = new ImageIcon(secImage.getImage().getScaledInstance((int)(secImage.getIconWidth() * 1.5), (int)(secImage.getIconHeight() * 1.5), Image.SCALE_DEFAULT));
        Icon icon = secImage;
        p2Gif = new JLabel(icon);

        ImageIcon firstImage = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("SpritesBack/" + name1 + "-back.gif"));
        firstImage = new ImageIcon(firstImage.getImage().getScaledInstance((int)(firstImage.getIconWidth() * 1.5), (int)(firstImage.getIconHeight() * 1.5), Image.SCALE_DEFAULT));
        Icon icon2 = firstImage;
        p1Gif = new JLabel(icon2);

        animationPanel.add(healthBar2);
        animationPanel.add(p2Gif);
        animationPanel.add(p1Gif);
        animationPanel.add(healthBar1);

        updateAll();
    }

    public void fillPortions(int x) {
        JLabel [] labels = new JLabel[x];
        for (int i = 0; i < x; i ++) {
            labels[i] = new JLabel();
            animationPanel.add(labels[i]);
        }
    }

    public void refreshHealthBar(int health, int total, int pNum, int mon) {

        if (pNum == 1) {
            if (p1MonNum != mon && p1MonNum != -1) {
                p1MonNum = mon;

                health1 = health;
                total1 = total;

                healthBar1.setHealth(health);
                healthBar1.setTotal(total);

                redoHealthPanel();
            }
            else {
                p1MonNum = mon;
                healthBar1.setTotal(total);;
                while (health < health1) {

                    healthBar1.setHealth(health1);

                    redoHealthPanel();

                    health1--;
                }

                while (health > health1) {

                    healthBar1.setHealth(health1);

                    redoHealthPanel();

                    health1++;
                }
            }
        }
        else {
            if (p2MonNum != mon && p2MonNum != -1) {
                p2MonNum = mon;

                health2 = health;
                total2 = total;

                healthBar2.setHealth(health);
                healthBar2.setTotal(total);

                redoHealthPanel();

                updateAll();
            }
            else {
                p2MonNum = mon;
                healthBar2.setTotal(total);
                while (health < health2) {

                    healthBar2.setHealth(health2);

                    redoHealthPanel();

                    health2--;
                }

                while (health > health2) {

                    healthBar2.setHealth(health2);

                    redoHealthPanel();

                    health2++;
                }
            }
        }

    }

    private void redoHealthPanel () {
        animationPanel.removeAll();

        animationPanel.add(healthBar2);
        animationPanel.add(p2Gif);
        animationPanel.add(p1Gif);
        animationPanel.add(healthBar1);

        updateAll();

        try {
            TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(waitTime);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private String validatePokemon() {

        String answer = "";

        String tempMonNames [] = new String[6];

        boolean invalidMove = false;

        for (int i = 0; i < monPanels.length; i ++) {

            String currentName = names[i].getText();

            if (currentName.isEmpty()) {

                answer = "You must have 6 Pokemon on your team but you can have less than 4 moves";
                return answer;

            }

            for (String element : tempMonNames) {

                if (element == null) {

                    continue;

                } else if (currentName.equals(element)) {

                    answer = "You have duplicate Pokemon on your team";

                    return answer;

                }
            }

            if (!info.validPokemon(currentName)) {

                answer += "Pokemon #" + (i + 1) + " is invalid\n";

            } else {

                tempMonNames[i] = currentName;

            }

            int count = 0;

            for (int k = 0; k < moves[i].length; k++) {

                if (moves[i][k].getText().isEmpty()) {

                    count++;

                }

                if (!info.validMove(moves[i][k].getText().replace(" ", "").toLowerCase(), currentName)) {

                    answer += "Pokemon #" + (i + 1) + ", move #" + (k + 1) + " is invalid\n";
                    invalidMove = true;

                }

                if (count >= 4) {

                    answer += "Pokemon #" + (i + 1) + " has no moves\n";
                    break;

                }

            }

        }

        if (invalidMove) {

            answer += "***Please keep in mind only damaging moves without recoil are allowed, if there aren't enough for 4 moves, leave fields blank***";

        }

        return answer;

    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        if (validatePokemon().isEmpty()) {

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Confirmed" , "", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);

        } else {

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, validatePokemon() , "", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);

        }
    }


    @Override
    public void caretUpdate(CaretEvent e) {

        for (int i = 0; i < names.length; i ++) {

            if (info.validPokemon(names[i].getText()) && tempImages[i].getParent() == null) {

                ImageIcon temp = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("SpritesFront/" + names[i].getText().replace(" ", "").replace(":", "").replace("'", "").replace(".", "").replace("-", "").toLowerCase() + ".gif"));
                temp = new ImageIcon(temp.getImage().getScaledInstance((int)(temp.getIconWidth() * 1.5), (int)(temp.getIconHeight() * 1.5), Image.SCALE_DEFAULT));
                Icon icon = temp;

                imagePanels[i].remove(tempImages[i]);

                tempImages[i] = new JLabel(icon);

                imagePanels[i].add(tempImages[i]);

                updateAll();

            } else if (!info.validPokemon(names[i].getText())){

                imagePanels[i].remove(tempImages[i]);

                updateAll();

            }

        }
    }

}
```

This is set up for the window:

```
        GraphicsPanel window = new GraphicsPanel("Pokemon");
        window.setBounds(0, 0, 1440, 830);
        window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        window.setVisible(true);
```

This is where the `getX()` and `getY()` are getting called:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.util.*;

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.LineBorder;
import javax.swing.event.DocumentEvent;
import javax.swing.event.DocumentListener;
import javax.swing.text.BadLocationException;
import javax.swing.text.JTextComponent;

public class AutoSuggestor {

    private final JTextComponent textComp;
    private JPanel suggestionsPanel;
    private JWindow autoSuggestionPopUpWindow;
    private String typedWord;
    private final ArrayList<String> dictionary = new ArrayList<>();
    private JTextField textField;
    private int currentIndexOfSpace, tW, tH;
    private DocumentListener documentListener = new DocumentListener() {
        @Override
        public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent de) {
            checkForAndShowSuggestions();
        }

        @Override
        public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent de) {
            checkForAndShowSuggestions();
        }

        @Override
        public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent de) {
            checkForAndShowSuggestions();
        }
    };
    private final Color suggestionsTextColor;
    private final Color suggestionFocusedColor;

    public AutoSuggestor(JTextComponent textComp, ArrayList<String> words, Color popUpBackground, Color textColor, Color suggestionFocusedColor, float opacity) {
        this.textComp = textComp;
        this.suggestionsTextColor = textColor;
        this.suggestionFocusedColor = suggestionFocusedColor;
        this.textComp.getDocument().addDocumentListener(documentListener);

        setDictionary(words);

        typedWord = "";
        currentIndexOfSpace = 0;
        tW = 0;
        tH = 0;

        autoSuggestionPopUpWindow = new JWindow();
        autoSuggestionPopUpWindow.setOpacity(opacity);

        suggestionsPanel = new JPanel();
        suggestionsPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 1));
        suggestionsPanel.setBackground(popUpBackground);

        addKeyBindingToRequestFocusInPopUpWindow();
    }

    private void addKeyBindingToRequestFocusInPopUpWindow() {
        textComp.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_FOCUSED).put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_DOWN, 0, true), "Down released");
        textComp.getActionMap().put("Down released", new AbstractAction() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {//focuses the first label on popwindow
                for (int i = 0; i < suggestionsPanel.getComponentCount(); i++) {
                    if (suggestionsPanel.getComponent(i) instanceof SuggestionLabel) {
                        ((SuggestionLabel) suggestionsPanel.getComponent(i)).setFocused(true);
                        autoSuggestionPopUpWindow.toFront();
                        autoSuggestionPopUpWindow.requestFocusInWindow();
                        suggestionsPanel.requestFocusInWindow();
                        suggestionsPanel.getComponent(i).requestFocusInWindow();
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        suggestionsPanel.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_ANCESTOR_OF_FOCUSED_COMPONENT).put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_DOWN, 0, true), "Down released");
        suggestionsPanel.getActionMap().put("Down released", new AbstractAction() {
            int lastFocusableIndex = 0;

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {//allows scrolling of labels in pop window (I know very hacky for now :))

                ArrayList<SuggestionLabel> sls = getAddedSuggestionLabels();
                int max = sls.size();

                if (max > 1) {//more than 1 suggestion
                    for (int i = 0; i < max; i++) {
                        SuggestionLabel sl = sls.get(i);
                        if (sl.isFocused()) {
                            if (lastFocusableIndex == max - 1) {
                                lastFocusableIndex = 0;
                                sl.setFocused(false);
                                autoSuggestionPopUpWindow.setVisible(false);
                                setFocusToTextField();
                                checkForAndShowSuggestions();//fire method as if document listener change occured and fired it

                            } else {
                                sl.setFocused(false);
                                lastFocusableIndex = i;
                            }
                        } else if (lastFocusableIndex <= i) {
                            if (i < max) {
                                sl.setFocused(true);
                                autoSuggestionPopUpWindow.toFront();
                                autoSuggestionPopUpWindow.requestFocusInWindow();
                                suggestionsPanel.requestFocusInWindow();
                                suggestionsPanel.getComponent(i).requestFocusInWindow();
                                lastFocusableIndex = i;
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                } else {//only a single suggestion was given
                    autoSuggestionPopUpWindow.setVisible(false);
                    setFocusToTextField();
                    checkForAndShowSuggestions();//fire method as if document listener change occured and fired it
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private void setFocusToTextField() {
        textComp.requestFocusInWindow();
    }

    public ArrayList<SuggestionLabel> getAddedSuggestionLabels() {
        ArrayList<SuggestionLabel> sls = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < suggestionsPanel.getComponentCount(); i++) {
            if (suggestionsPanel.getComponent(i) instanceof SuggestionLabel) {
                SuggestionLabel sl = (SuggestionLabel) suggestionsPanel.getComponent(i);
                sls.add(sl);
            }
        }
        return sls;
    }

    private void checkForAndShowSuggestions() {
        typedWord = getCurrentlyTypedWord();

        suggestionsPanel.removeAll();//remove previos words/jlabels that were added

        //used to calcualte size of JWindow as new Jlabels are added
        tW = 0;
        tH = 0;

        boolean added = wordTyped(typedWord);

        if (!added) {
            if (autoSuggestionPopUpWindow.isVisible()) {
                autoSuggestionPopUpWindow.setVisible(false);
            }
        } else {
            showPopUpWindow();
            setFocusToTextField();
        }
    }

    protected void addWordToSuggestions(String word) {
        SuggestionLabel suggestionLabel = new SuggestionLabel(word, suggestionFocusedColor, suggestionsTextColor, this);

        calculatePopUpWindowSize(suggestionLabel);

        suggestionsPanel.add(suggestionLabel);
    }

    public String getCurrentlyTypedWord() {//get newest word after last white spaceif any or the first word if no white spaces
        String text = textComp.getText();
        String wordBeingTyped = "";
        text = text.replaceAll("(\\r|\\n)", " ");
        if (text.contains(" ")) {
            int tmp = text.lastIndexOf(" ");
            if (tmp >= currentIndexOfSpace) {
                currentIndexOfSpace = tmp;
                wordBeingTyped = text.substring(text.lastIndexOf(" "));
            }
        } else {
            wordBeingTyped = text;
        }
        return wordBeingTyped.trim();
    }

    private void calculatePopUpWindowSize(JLabel label) {
        //so we can size the JWindow correctly
        if (tW < label.getPreferredSize().width) {
            tW = label.getPreferredSize().width;
        }
        tH += label.getPreferredSize().height;
    }

    public void setTextField(JTextField textField) {

        this.textField = textField;

    }

    private void showPopUpWindow() {
        autoSuggestionPopUpWindow.getContentPane().add(suggestionsPanel);
        autoSuggestionPopUpWindow.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(textComp.getWidth(), 30));
        autoSuggestionPopUpWindow.setSize(tW, tH);
        autoSuggestionPopUpWindow.setVisible(true);

        //show the pop up
        autoSuggestionPopUpWindow.setLocation(textComp.getX(), textComp.getY() + textComp.getHeight());
        autoSuggestionPopUpWindow.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(textComp.getWidth(), 30));
        autoSuggestionPopUpWindow.revalidate();
        autoSuggestionPopUpWindow.repaint();

    }

    public void setDictionary(ArrayList<String> words) {
        dictionary.clear();
        if (words == null) {
            return;//so we can call constructor with null value for dictionary without exception thrown
        }
        for (String word : words) {
            dictionary.add(word);
        }
    }

    public JWindow getAutoSuggestionPopUpWindow() {
        return autoSuggestionPopUpWindow;
    }

    public JTextComponent getTextField() {
        return textComp;
    }

    public void addToDictionary(String word) {
        dictionary.add(word);
    }

    boolean wordTyped(String typedWord) {

        if (typedWord.isEmpty()) {
            return false;
        }
        //System.out.println("Typed word: " + typedWord);

        boolean suggestionAdded = false;

        for (String word : dictionary) {//get words in the dictionary which we added
            boolean fullymatches = true;
            for (int i = 0; i < typedWord.length(); i++) {//each string in the word
                if (!typedWord.toLowerCase().startsWith(String.valueOf(word.toLowerCase().charAt(i)), i)) {//check for match
                    fullymatches = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (fullymatches) {
                addWordToSuggestions(word);
                suggestionAdded = true;
            }
        }
        return suggestionAdded;
    }
}

class SuggestionLabel extends JLabel {

    private boolean focused = false;
    private final JWindow autoSuggestionsPopUpWindow;
    private final JTextComponent textComponent;
    private final AutoSuggestor autoSuggestor;
    private Color suggestionsTextColor, suggestionBorderColor;

    public SuggestionLabel(String string, final Color borderColor, Color suggestionsTextColor, AutoSuggestor autoSuggestor) {
        super(string);

        this.suggestionsTextColor = suggestionsTextColor;
        this.autoSuggestor = autoSuggestor;
        this.textComponent = autoSuggestor.getTextField();
        this.suggestionBorderColor = borderColor;
        this.autoSuggestionsPopUpWindow = autoSuggestor.getAutoSuggestionPopUpWindow();

        initComponent();
    }

    private void initComponent() {
        setFocusable(true);
        setForeground(suggestionsTextColor);

        addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent me) {
                super.mouseClicked(me);

                replaceWithSuggestedText();

                autoSuggestionsPopUpWindow.setVisible(false);
            }
        });

        getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_FOCUSED).put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER, 0, true), "Enter released");
        getActionMap().put("Enter released", new AbstractAction() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                replaceWithSuggestedText();
                autoSuggestionsPopUpWindow.setVisible(false);
            }
        });
    }

    public void setFocused(boolean focused) {
        if (focused) {
            setBorder(new LineBorder(suggestionBorderColor));
        } else {
            setBorder(null);
        }
        repaint();
        this.focused = focused;
    }

    public boolean isFocused() {
        return focused;
    }

    private void replaceWithSuggestedText() {
        String suggestedWord = getText();
        String text = textComponent.getText();
        String typedWord = autoSuggestor.getCurrentlyTypedWord();
        String t = text.substring(0, text.lastIndexOf(typedWord));
        String tmp = t + text.substring(text.lastIndexOf(typedWord)).replace(typedWord, suggestedWord);
        textComponent.setText(tmp);
    }
}
```

The `textComp.getX()` and `textComp.getY()` in the showPopUpWindow method are the ones that are giving zeros.

Comment: If you don't give us the full code that doesn't work, how do you think we would be able to help? Please give us a [MCVE]

Comment: Sorry about that the entire code is too much for me to put up there, if there is anything more that is needed I can try and add it.

Comment: Then you have to simplify it!

Comment: Is whatever I just added not enough, if so what else should I be adding.

Comment: The problem is likely that the text field is reporting its position relative to the parent container rather than the frame as you were expecting. *"I needed to get the x and y coordinates of one of the text fields"* On that, *why?* See [What is the XY problem?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377) General tips: You've posted two classes above that comprise > 800 lines of code, neither of which seems to contain a `main(String[])` method that can be used to run the code. I urge you to **carefully read** both linked articles (below) & try to understand the meaning of / implement an MRE / SSCCE.

Comment: For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Answer (score 0):

After thinking about it for a while I came up with this solution and it works for me.

```
int x = 0;
int y = 0;

Component currentComponent = textComp;

while (currentComponent != null) {

    x += currentComponent.getX();
    y += currentComponent.getY();

    currentComponent = currentComponent.getParent();

}
```